# Spring batch : reading a csv file and modify this list before putting the results in another file

Tags: java, spring, list, csv, spring-batch

i have a csv file i retreive i retrieve all of these lines and I put these lines in another csv file.

I need to make a change on this list. For example group all the lines which have the same type in a single line and the sum of an integer type column for example.

can someone help me ? 
I lost a lot of time to realize this little spot.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

A small example to explain.

I want to achieve something like this

The input file :

A     1

A     2

B     1

B     3

the output file should be like this

A     3 ( 1+2 )

B     4 ( 1+3 )

Comment: What problems do you have?

Comment: @BogdanK thank u for ur reply i need to make change and and feltering the list before putting data in outputs file 
Here is the link of the details 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946067/spring-batch-retrieve-the-list-of-objects-from-file-and-return-of-a-single-line](Here is the link of the details )

Comment: @BogdanK you have an idea?

Comment: you can retrieve all from file on a `step of reader` and pass to `processor`, on `processor` make all data operation and on `writer` need to  write all to new file

Comment: @BogdanK I recuperate all data from file 10 line so it makes 10 object for example I use FieldSetMapper to map each object. Processor will be called 10 times while I in the output file I want to group my lines and having just 5 lines for example

Comment: @BogdanK I want the processor to be called only once and receive the entire list and do some operations and return a new list to write it in the new file

Comment: you can configure how many times processor will be called.
As far as i understood from your comment, your processor called for each items, but you need to set that processor will be called for bulk items, for example it can be 100 items

Comment: Why do you need to do it with Spring Batch?
Batch used for doing operations in processors in different threads, but if you want that processor will called one times then I'm not sure you need to use Spring Batch

Comment: @BogdanK Because it's batch jobs it's job among others. 
For example I have 100 lines but in output I have to group these lines with lines that have the same type

Comment: @Rodik why don't you use External DB. processor or writer aggregating data might worker for smaller data. But when there are large number of records in csv file, it might not be efficient and fault tolerant. If you still want to go with it then you can create itemAggregateWriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with two steps and SpringBean in which you store your temporary results.

First, you need a Spring Bean which you can use to sum up:

```
@Component
public class SummaryCache {
   private Map<String, Integer> summaryMap = new Hashmap<>();

   public void addValue(String id, Integer value) { 
       summaryMap.merge(id, value, (curVal, toAddVal) -> curVal.int() + toAddVal.int());

   }   
}
```

Next, you need a processor, with uses the above SummaryCache.

```
@Autowired
private SummaryCache cache;

public ItemProcessor<YourDto> createProcessor() {
   return item -> {
          cache.addValue(item.getId(), item.getValue();
          return item;
   };
}
```

The writer of this first step ist a passthrough itemwriter, so it does nothing.

```
   public ItemWriter<YourDto> createWriter() {
       return items -> {};
   }
```

Of course, instead of having an empty writer, you could also implement the logic of the processor in the writer and skip the processor.

That completes the first step.

The second step could simply be a TaskletStep, that takes the SummaryCache as input (Autowire it) and writes a line in a file for every entry.

The main disadvantage of this approach is, that you have to process the whole file completely, therefore, no restart is possible. But since you are reading from a file, that is not really an issues when it comes to performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for ur reply, I lost a lot of time to realize this.